# Radix sort for strings of arbitrary lengths

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, radix-sort

I need to sort a huge list of text strings of arbitrary length. I suppose radix sort is the best option here. List is really huge, so padding strings to the same length is completely impossible.
Is there any ready-made implementation for this task, preferably in C#?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the question. First, why would you need any padding? You need padding for LSD radix sort, but presumably since you are sorting strings you want a MSD radix sort, since that produces a lexicographical order. Second, if the strings are of *arbitrary* length, then isn't radix sort *less* efficient than a comparison sort? Yes, you do O(n lg n) comparisons in a comparison sort, but you do O(kn) operations in a radix sort. *If k can be arbitrarily large then this can be very inefficient*. Can you explain further?

Comment: And third, radix sort depends on the number of "buckets" being small. There are tens of thousands of possible first characters for a string, which is not a small number. Do you know something about the strings that you're not saying, like that they contain only uppercase Roman letters or something?

Comment: @Eric Lippert, well, lets forget about padding. MSD is ok. However, comparisons for these two algorithms aren't the same in cost, coz whole strings comparison can take much more time then chars comparison. Thus, you can't just compare number of comparisons (heh, sounds funny :). And yes, in my case number of buckets is quite small. It's limited to digits and latin chars.

Comment: @Eric Lippert - You can always treat the string as an array of bytes in which case there are only 256 possible values.  Of course, easier said than done in C#.

Comment: @Eric Lippert - you are also forgetting that a comparison sort on strings actually takes O(nklog(n)) time.

Comment: @Niki Yoshiuchi, treating a string as an array of bytes is the absolute worst thing you can do.  Array of chars would be closer to better, but still not good.  Unicode makes those kind of tricks bad juju.

Comment: Yeah, you're right - I didn't think things through too well.  If you sort on byte value then you are no longer guaranteed alphabetical order.

Comment: How big is "really huge"?  Tens of millions of lines?  Hundreds of millions?

Comment: @Niki: the vast majority of string comparisons on *typical* data sets work out which string is larger than another in a very small number of char comparisons, without having to compare all k chars in the string. Almost noone is comparing strings where every string begins "banananananananananananana" for ten thousand characters and then ends in a unique suffix! String comparisons are only expensive if they are (1) not reference equal and (2) have long similar prefixes.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Yes, of course.  We don't know anything about the data set but it's not too presumptuous to assume that long similar prefixes will be rare, in which case a large set of large strings might be better sorted using a comparison sort.

Comment: @Niki: and besides, let's suppose for the sake of argument that there *are* lots of long strings with lengthy identical prefixes, so that comparisons become expensive. As Rex points out in his answer, *that's a pathologically bad case for radix sort too*.

Comment: @jifuyo: Returning to the problem at hand: has your performance analysis demonstrated conclusively that the built-in quicksort implementation is too slow for your customers? If it has not then *do that performance analysis first*. Only if the off-the-shelf solution is too slow should you be considering changing up the algorithm.

Comment: @Eric Lipper, is it really? Radix sort performs equally, whether there are long equal string prefixes or not. And yes, I do have lots of strings with equal prefixes. And yes again, built-in sort routine is way too slow for my task.

Comment: @jifuyo: Where are you getting the strings from?  What are you doing with them?  Have you considered storing them in a Trie?  Depending on the implementation it can be O(n*k) to insert all the strings.  Actually, Tries are basically the data structure equivalent to a radix sort.

Comment: @jifuyo: I would naively think that the allocation cost of making all those buckets with a small number of items in them overwhelms the savings, but hey, I haven't profiled it. I suppose you could avoid the allocation cost by doing the sort in-place, if you're into destructive sorting.

Comment: @Niki: Good point about a trie. More generally, instead of having an unordered list to begin with, could you simply have an ordered list (stored as a balanced binary tree, for example) and then you take on the sorting cost as items are added and removed, not all at once?  That's probably more expensive on a total-cost basis but if the edits are rare then it might be cheaper on a per-operation basis.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you need, you might find inserting all the strings into some form of Trie to be the best solution.  Even a basic Ternary Search Trie will have a smaller memory footprint than an array/list of strings and will store the strings in sorted order.

Insertion, lookup and removal are all `O(k * log(a))` where `a` is the size of your alphabet (the number of possible values for a character).  Since `a` is constant so is `log(a)` so you end up with a `O(n * k)` algorithm for sorting.

Edit: In case you are unfamiliar with Tries, they are basically n-ary trees where each edge represents a single character of the key.  When inserting, you check if the root node contains an edge (or child, whatever) that matches the first character of your key.  If so, you follow that path and repeat with the second character and so on.  If not, you add a new edge.  In a Ternary Search Trie, the edges/children are stored in a binary tree so the characters are in sorted order and can be searched in `log(a)` time.  If you want to waste memory you can store the edges/children in an array of size `a` which gives you constant lookup at each step.

Comment: Well, I can try this way too. I'm just researching possible ways to speed up my task. Better if you know a ready-made code for it ;)

Comment: A quick google search revealed a few implementations, but the ones I looked at assumed Roman characters and case insensitive comparisons.  They also either used either arrays or lists to store nodes which is not necessarily the most efficient way to do it (arrays waste space, lists mean `O(a)` lookup).

Comment: I have an implementation of a ternary search trie on my computer (in OCaml so useless for you) and decided to run some tests.  I concatenated a whole bunch of C++ source files together and sorted that using my trie and List.sort.  List.sort was more than 3 times faster.  Then I catted that big file with itself 8 times (to create duplicates) after which List.sort was a little less than 3 times as fast(9s to 26s).  Finally I made a file with the same line repeated 10^7 times.  The trie was twice as fast (27s to 52s).

Answer (score 1):

See this thread. [radix sort](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/123702-sorting-strings-from-text-file-using-radix-sort/)   or this one [radix sort implementation](http://www.weask.us/entry/ready-made-implementation-radix-sort)

Answer (score 1):

How many are many, one million?

The built in [`List<string>.Sort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(%22SYSTEM.COLLECTIONS.GENERIC.LIST%601.SORT%22);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true) takes O(n * log(n)) on average.

log2(10^6) ~=20, that is not very much slower than O(n) for 10^6 elements. If your strings are more than 20 characters long radix sort O(n * k) will be "slower".

I doubt a radix sort will be significantly faster than the built in sort. But it would be fun to measure and compare.

Comment: 1. comparisons of whole strings (for quicksort) and chars (for radix sort) are very different in cost  2. quicksort takes O(n * log(n)) only in average, but it takes O(n^2) in the worst case

Comment: @jifuyo - Do you have any reason to suspect you might hit a worst-case scenario?  And if so, why not just use mergesort?  And how do you intend to not need to look at every character in a string to separate two strings different only in the last character?  In radix sort, you have to look at the whole thing to put each in the right bucket; in mergesort you have to run to the end to do that comparison.

Comment: You're forgetting that each comparison in quick/merge/heap sort is going to require the use of a string compare, which is O(k), so the running time of List<string>.Sort() will take O(n*k*log(n)) on average.

Comment: @Niki Yoshiuchi string comparison takes O(k) in the worst case, but that requires lots of long strings with long common beginnings. If strings were infinite and random, the number of comparisons required on average would be some constant, obviously not dependent on the length of strings (which were infinite). What is the situation in real life I don't know, but I doubt the average complexity is O(k).

Comment: @Maciej Hehl: I'm aware.  I just don't think it's safe to ignore the possibility, especially when we don't know anything about the data set (think lots of duplicates).  Ultimately this is something that would require benchmarking or knowledge of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: there is a point to these statements I made previously, but the point is wrong overall.

Radix sort is the wrong sort to use on large numbers of strings.  For things like

```
I really like squirrels. Yay, yay, yay!
I really like blue jays. Yay, yay, yay!
I really like registers. Yay, yay, yay!
```

you will have a bunch of entries falling in the same bucket.  You could avoid this by hashing, but what use is sorting a hash code?

Use quicksort or mergesort or the like.  (Quicksort generally performs better and takes less memory, but many examples have worst-case performance of O(N^2) which almost never occurs in practice; Mergesort doesn't perform quite as well but is usually implemented to be stable, and it's easy to do part in memory and part on disk.)  That is, use the built-in sort function.

---

Edit: Well, it turns out that at least on very large files with long repeats at the beginning (e.g. source code) and with many lines exactly the same (100x repeats, in fact), radix sort does start becoming competitive with quicksort.  I'm surprised!  But, anyway, here is the code I used to implement radix sort.  It's in Scala, not C#, but I've written it in fairly iterative style so it should be reasonably obvious how things work.  The only two tricky bits are that `(a(i)(ch) & 0xFF)` is to extract a 0-255 byte from an array of arrays of bytes (bytes are signed), that `counts.scanLeft(0)(_ + _)` forms a cumulative sum of the counts, starting from zero (and then `indices.clone.take(257)` takes all but the last one), and that Scala allows multiple parameter lists (so I split up the always-provided argument from the arguments that have defaults that are used in recursion).  Here it is:

```
def radixSort(a: Array[Array[Byte]])(i0: Int = 0, i1: Int = a.length, ch: Int = 0) {
  val counts = new Array[Int](257)
  var i = i0
  while (i < i1) {
    if (a(i).length <= ch) counts(0) += 1
    else { counts((a(i)(ch)&0xFF)+1) += 1 }
    i += 1
  }
  val indices = counts.scanLeft(0)(_ + _)
  val starts = indices.clone.take(257)
  i = i0
  while (i < i1) {
    val bucket = if (a(i).length <= ch) 0 else (a(i)(ch)&0xFF)+1
    if (starts(bucket)+i0 <= i && i < starts(bucket)+i0+counts(bucket)) {
      if (indices(bucket) <= i) indices(bucket) = i+1
      i += 1
    }
    else {
      val temp = a(indices(bucket)+i0)
      a(indices(bucket)+i0) = a(i)
      a(i) = temp
      indices(bucket) += 1
    }
  }
  i = 1
  while (i < counts.length) {
    if (counts(i)>1) {
      radixSort(a)(i0+starts(i),i0+starts(i)+counts(i),ch+1)
    }
    i += 1
  }
}
```

And the timings are that with 7M lines of source code (100x duplication of 70k lines), the radix sort ties the built-in library sort, and wins thereafter.

Comment: Yes, lots of items in the same bucket. Is this a problem?

Comment: @jifuyo - They're not sorted, and you don't know how many there are.  So you need to create a resizable array or a tree to hold your pointers, and then you have to bucket again recursively.  This gives you `O(N log N)` performance and considerable memory usage even if you're really careful, since you need to generate buckets any time you have confused strings.  And then, don't forget that you have to weigh a string compare and pointer manipulation against a char index lookup and creation and maintenance of an array of stored values.

Comment: @jifuyo - Fair enough - if you're allowing two-pass methods, you need at least `O(K*B)` memory to store the bin boundaries, where `K` is the length of the string and `B` is the size of the allowable character set.  Still more than quicksort's `O(log N)` in most cases, but pretty insignificant compared to the strings themselves.

Answer (score -2):

String.Compare() overloads are using such string comparison. See what you need is to feed this to your 
sort algorithm.

**UPDATE**

This is the implementation:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
internal static extern int nativeCompareString(int lcid, string string1, int offset1, int length1, string string2, int offset2, int length2, int flags);
```

Hard to beat this native unmanaged implementation with your own implementation.

Comment: This does not look like radix sort to me.

Comment: Radix sort is not a comparison sort so a string compare function is useless.

Comment: The question is how to *avoid* using a whole-string comparison, not *which one to use*. The whole point of radix sort is that it does *no* string-to-string comparisons, only char comparisons.

Comment: But this one compares the strings char by char and will return as soon as one does not match. So I cannot understand the negatives!

Comment: @Eric - String comparisons are built out of char comparisons.  What is your point?

Comment: @Rex - at each step in a radix sort you are doing single char comparisons.  At each step in a comparison sort you are doing a string compare.

Comment: @Rex: My point is that you never need to call String.Compare in a radix sort; the whole point of radix sort is that you do *not* need to do a whole-string comparison.  You don't need to do any *ordering* comparison at all, only an *equality* comparison on chars.